# Azure TTS timeout python

Tags: python, azure, text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services

Hi i have this problem with [**Azure TTS**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/speech-service/) when i try to use the python **`Text to speech quickstart`example** i get this **error**

```
...> python example.py
Enter some text that you want to speak >
test
Speech synthesis canceled: CancellationReason.Error
Error details: USP error: timeout waiting for the first audio chunk
Did you set the speech resource key and region values?
```

Using Python **3.11**.4
**Azure Speech to text works normally **

Answer (score 0):

I followed the given [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/speech-service/get-started-text-to-speech?tabs=macos,terminal&pivots=programming-language-python) and I got the speech output with the input text.

**Code:**

```py
import os
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk

speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=os.environ.get('SPEECH_KEY'), region=os.environ.get('SPEECH_REGION'))
audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioOutputConfig(use_default_speaker=True)

speech_config.speech_synthesis_voice_name='en-US-JennyNeural'

speech_synthesizer = speechsdk.SpeechSynthesizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)

print("Enter text that you want to speak >")
text = input()

speech_synthesis_result = speech_synthesizer.speak_text_async(text).get()

if speech_synthesis_result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted:
    print("Speech synthesized for text [{}]".format(text))
elif speech_synthesis_result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.Canceled:
    cancellation_details = speech_synthesis_result.cancellation_details
    print("Speech synthesis canceled: {}".format(cancellation_details.reason))
    if cancellation_details.reason == speechsdk.CancellationReason.Error:
        if cancellation_details.error_details:
            print("Error details: {}".format(cancellation_details.error_details))
            print("Did you set speech resource key and region?")
```

**. env** :

```py
SPEECH_KEY="<specch_key>"
SPEECH_REGION="<speech_region>"
```

Before going to run the above code you need to set **SPEECH_KEY** and **SPEECH_REGION** in **System Environment Variables** like below,

[image]

**Output:**

It runs successfully as below,

[image]

Then, I enter a line as **Hi kamali, How are you. How is kasimbi?** like below and it gives speech output.

[image]

As an alternative, You can also try another code for the text-to-speech below,

**Code** :

```py
import os
from azure.cognitiveservices.speech import AudioDataStream, ResultReason, SpeechConfig, SpeechSynthesizer, SpeechSynthesisOutputFormat

subscription_key = "<speech_key>"
region = "<speech_region>"

speech_config = SpeechConfig(subscription=subscription_key, region=region)
synthesizer = SpeechSynthesizer(speech_config=speech_config)

try:
    text = input("Enter some text that you want to speak > ")
    result = synthesizer.speak_text_async(text).get()
    
    if result.reason == ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted:
        print("Speech synthesis succeeded")
    else:
        print("Speech synthesis failed: {}".format(result.reason))
    
except Exception as e:
    print("An error occurred: {}".format(e))
```

**Output** :

It runs successfully and gives the speech output with input text as below,

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks for the anwser but i already set the ENV
The speech to text works perfectly its just tts that is broken

Comment: @AshKetchumPL This error could be due to network issues, server load, or misconfiguration. Can you try to run the code in a different network environment, such as another Wi-Fi network or using a cellular connection, to see if the issue persists?